# setting parameters of array type using hex taken from the panel

Tags: type-conversion, parameter-passing, capl, canoe

I'm currently writing a CAPL script that would take the parameters from a panel and create UDS requests with it.

In the panel I have a hex/text editor which I use to get bytes that would be later used to fill some parameters of type array and I don't know how to set those parameters using this data.

ex:

The UDS service "ReadDataByIdentifier" takes as a parameter an array of integers which would represent the several DIDs.
[image]

To take these parameters I simply added a hex/text Editor in my panel which would allow the user to enter bytes representing the DIDs.

[image]

The problem is I don't know how to use this input to set the parameters.

I tried using the "diagSetParameterCoded" function but it requires a pointer to a byte array and all I have is an environment variable of type integer array or of type data.

Comment: You should be able to create a byte array in your code and fill it by using `sysGetVariableData`